# Problem with the function update of cron-job-manager

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, parameters, cron

I'm using the lib `cron-job-manager` to manage my cron because i'm running multiple crons in my app but i have an issue when i want to update the specific cron i do it like this:

```
manager.update(alertData.id.toString(), cronFinal)
```

But it's not working when i see the function it take this as arguments:

```
update(...args: any): void
```

The documentation says

You may want to change the task, time or both of any job during execution. You can do so using the update function

```
manager.update('key', '0 15 3,5,9,14,18,20 * * *', () => {// do this instead on this new schedule
});
manager.update('key', () => { // do this instead 
});
manager.update('key', '0 15 3,5,9,14,18,20 * * *') // do it on this schedule instead.
```

The error i have is this one;

```
error updating tab: 33 - Cannot read property 'running' of undefined
```

33 corresponding to the `id.toString()` i'm using

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong pls ?

Thanks by advance :D